# How to fix out of focus issue on input text in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have been building Login page and facing this problem.

I have multiple component like `<Section/>, <Container/>, <FormLayout/>, <InputText/>`.

Login page

```
export default function Login() {
  const [mail,setMail] = useState('');
  const handleMailChange = (e) => {
    setMail(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <Section className="someClassName">
      <Container size="l" wrapper={true}>
        <section className="someClassName">
          <Container size="s" className="someClassName">
            <FormLayout arg1="" arg2="">
              <InputText
                type="email"
                value={mail}
                onChange={handleMailChange}
              />
            </FormLayout>
          </Container>
        </section>
      </Container>
    </Section>
  );
}
```

Components are defined like this in other files

```
const Section = ({ className = "", children }) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};

const Container = ({ size='', wrapper={false}, children }) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};

const InputText = ({ value = "", type = "text", onChange = "" }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(value);

  const handleChange = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      setText(event.target.value);
      if (typeof onChange === "function") {
        onChange(event);
      }
    },
    [onChange]
  );

  return <input value={text} type={type} onChange={handleChange} />;
};
```

I found that every time I type any character `Section` re-renders and input box is out of the focus. How can i fix this problem ?

Edit: I was able to generate this problem [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/longin-react-page-xti4jj).

Comment: not sure it's relevant, but the inner `<section...` is different to `<Section...` - probably irrelevant though

Comment: Rerender shouldn't lose focus. It sounds like a component remount

Comment: @JaromandaX  yes <section... and <Section... is different.

Comment: @Anonymous use useRef hook with input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you declare nested components like:

```
const Section = ({ color = "", currentClass = "", children }) => {
  const Element = () => {
    if (color === "gray") {
      return (
        <div className={[styles.section, styles.gray, currentClass].join(" ")}>
          {children}
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className={[styles.section, currentClass].join(" ")}>
          {children}
        </div>
      );
    }
  };

  return <Element />;
};
```

This is a bad practice. Every time the `Section` component is rendered a new `Element` component is created and React can't keep track of the tree.

The easiest fix is to change the nested component to functions e.g. `<Element />` to `Element()`

Sections component:

```
const Section = ({ color = "", currentClass = "", children }) => {
  const Element = () => {
    if (color === "gray") {
      return (
        <div className={[styles.section, styles.gray, currentClass].join(" ")}>
          {children}
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className={[styles.section, currentClass].join(" ")}>
          {children}
        </div>
      );
    }
  };

  return Element();
};
```

You have to do the same with `Container`

Here is the working code:

[image: Edit LongIn React Page (forked)]

You can also move the nested components outside of the parent component

Comment: Hi Konrad, I'm confused about your answer, `Element()` returns the same result as `<Element />`, why it fixed the problem?

Could you please provide more information or share some online resources on this topic?

Comment: `Element()` calls a function, `<Element>` initializes a component

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to make `InputText` controlled and both uncontrolled at the same time, this may be what is causing your issue.

There is no need to keep a state value of input as it is now, rather just make it this:

```
const InputText = ({ value, type = "text", onChange }) => {
  return <input value={value} type={type} onChange={onChange} />;
};
```

Notice that I'm not defaulting these values, so if you still want to give it uncontrolled functionality it will work.

If there's another reason you need to keep local state of that input control, then you need to provide that context in the question.

Comment: I added codesandbox url. I tried this but did not fix problem. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm writing a different answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Extending on @Konrad's answer.

```
const Section = ({ color = "", currentClass = "", children }) => {
  const Element = () => {
    if (color === "gray") {
      return (
        <div className={[styles.section, styles.gray, currentClass].join(" ")}>
          {children}
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className={[styles.section, currentClass].join(" ")}>
          {children}
        </div>
      );
    }
  };

  return <Element />;
};
```

This is the problem component and you have the same problem in the `Container` component which is a little more complex.

The problem is that these `Element` components are recreated every time a re-render occurs and that will take away focus from the children. It seems that in both of your cases the only difference is the class names, so instead of creating a full new component to render based off prop changes, rather just store the effective changed prop values that you're passing down.

Like this:

```
const Section = ({ color = "", currentClass = "", children }) => {
  const effectiveClassArray = color === "gray" ?
    [styles.section, styles.gray, currentClass] :
    [styles.section, currentClass];

  return (
    <div className={effectiveClassArray.join(" ")}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Don't forget to do the same thing to your `Container` component.

Answer (score 0):

It is re-rendering because the **input field is dependent on mail state**. And whenever value change, the state update so it re-render.

And if you want to avoid this behavior use **useRef hook**.

Its general practice to use **useRef hook** with form fields (input, select etc) so that you don't need to keep updating the value of Field.

Here is the updated code for the InputText:-

```
import useRef from 'react';

const InputText = ({ type = "text" }) => {
    const inputRef = useRef();

    return <input 
        ref={inputRef}
        value={text} 
        type={type}
    />;
};
```